# javascript to search attributes in an XML document

Tags: javascript

i want to make a javascript that reads a XML document as an input (let say "C010.xml"), searches for certain tags and then returns the value within these tags.
For example, in the expression

> `<lesson_mode>normal</lesson_mode>`

to return the attribute "normal".

Could you suggest sth please?

Thanks!

Comment: "normal" isn't an attribute; it's a text node.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the XML first. Use `XMLHttpRequest` for that, then parse the response via `DOMParser` which returns a `Document` instance. Then you can just access the value like this: `doc.getElementsByTagName('lesson_node')[0].textContent`

I don't know what experience you have, so this is the basic structure:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'C010.xml', true);
xhr.onload = function () {
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var doc = parser.parseFromString(xhr.responseText, 'application/xml');
  var value = doc.getElementsByTagName('lesson_node')[0].textContent;
};
xhr.send(null);
```

Note that this is not by any means cross-browser nowadays. You would have to search for a slightly different way to parse the response in IE.